# A metric on $L^1$ using measure of set where $f$ is greater than a value

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I am working on a problem showing that the following function describes a metric on $L^1$ for any measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ for a measurable set $E$:

Let -- for $f, g: E \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable -- $d(f)$ be defined as

$$d(f) := \inf\{r > 0 \mid \mu(\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| > r\}) \leq r\}$$

and $d(f,g) := d(f - g)$. I want to show that $d$ is a metric on $L^1(E)$.

So I need to prove

1. $d(f,f) = 0 \quad\forall f$
2. $d(f,g) = d(g,f) \quad\forall f,g$
3. $d(f,h) \leq d(f,g) + d(g,h) \quad \forall f,g,h$

The first two traits were pretty straight forward using the definition of the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$, but I struggle showing the triangle inequality.

Comment: *Ideas:* Say $r_{f,h} \geq 0$ so that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ the inequality $r_{f,h} + \varepsilon > d(f,h)$ holds and using that to generate the inequality for any $g$. But at this point, I'm stuck for now. Would be grateful for hints/ideas.

Comment: Two observations (which may or may not be helpful...)
$$\{|f(x) -h(x)|\ge r\}\subseteq \{|f(x) -g(x)|+|g(x) -h(x)|\ge r\} \subseteq \{|f(x) -g(x)|\ge r/2\}\cup\{|g(x) -h(x)|\ge r/2\} \tag1$$
and
$$\mu(\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| > r\})\le\frac{\|f\|_{L^1(E)}}{r} \tag2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r>d(f)$, $s>d(g)$.

If $|f(x)+g(x)|> r+s$, then by the triangle inequality we have either $|f(x)|>r$ or $|g(x)|>s$.  From this we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\mu(\{x \in E \mid |f(x)+g(x)| > r+s\}) &\leq \mu(\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| > r\}\cup \{x \in E \mid |g(x)| > s\}) \\
&\leq \mu(\{x \in E \mid |f(x)| > r\}) + \mu(\{x \in E \mid |g(x)| > s\}) \\
&\leq r + s,
\end{align*}
so by definition, $d(f+g)\leq r+ s$.

Taking $r\to d(f)$ and $s\to d(g)$, we conclude that $d(f+g)\leq d(f)+d(g)$.

Finally, to complete the proof, we have
\begin{align*}d(f,h) & = d(f-h) = d(f-g+g-h) \\
&\leq d(f-g)+d(g-h) = d(f,g)+d(g,h).
\end{align*}